# Get items from list by id

Tags: c#, list, get

I am having problems getting the items from my list into a textbox. I’m using Windows forms in Visual Studio.

I have one form with some textboxes and put the inputs to a list. The list contains customers and the user gives the customer an id from one of the textboxes. Now I want to get all the items from the list to the next form.

I have the list in a public class:

```
public class myClassCustomer
{
    public List<customerInformation> cusInformation = new List<customerInformation>();

    public class customerInformation
    {
        public string customerId { get; set; }
        public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string adress { get; set; }
     }
```

And the code for saving the inputs in form1:

```
myClassCustomer myClassCustomer = new myClassCustomer()
customers.cusInformation.Add(new myProject.myClassCustomer.customerInformation
{
    customerId = txtCustomerId.Text,
    phoneNumber = txtPhonenumber.Text,
    adress = txtAdress.Text
});
```

Now in form2 this is what I have written so far:

```
public form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myClassCustomer myClassCustomer = new myClassCustomer();
}
```

Does anyone know how to get all the items from the list?

Comment: You've provided two seemingly different pieces of code. `Casecs` does not relate in any way to `myClassCustomer` that I can see...

Comment: Yeah I must have done womething wrong when I copied the code. That should be:
myClassCustomer myClassCustomer = new myClassCustomer();

Comment: ..okay. So what is `customers`? That too is a class? Please provide proper code.

Comment: Sorry my mistace now that is fixed

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming that the question boils down to how to "*get all of the items from the list to the next form*", rather than the title suggests "*get items from list by id*".

The question "Anyone knows how to get all the items from the list?" is a bit tautological because the list already is all of the items.

So I am going to focus on answering your question about the list items being available to the next form. I presume that "Customers" is essentially just a List, and if it isn't, you should probably consider using that instead of a homebrew list class unless you have a very specific requirement otherwise. At the very least, I am hoping that the customers class implements the IEnumerable interface.

In order for this other form to be able to access your list of customers, you need to be making that information available somehow: for instance, you could change the other form's constructor to require a list of customers. Then, when this original form invokes the second form, it must pass in that list it has presumably populated as a parameter.

There are a few other ways this information could be propagated around your application but it sounds like you're just at a beginner level, so the method given above is probably the simplest.

Perhaps you could clarify your question if this does not answer it.

**Edit**: Some of your own edits have changed the code I was commenting on. It now appears that you're not after a list, but the advice is the same; instead of passing a List, you're just passing a myClassCustomer.

Comment: Okay and how do I change the other form's constructor to require a list om customers?

Comment: So for instance, say your other form had a default constructor that probably looks something like:

>    public Otherform() {
         Initialise();
    }

You might change it to:

>    public OtherForm(List<myCustomerClass> customers) {
        Initialise();
        SomeList = customers;
     }

Presuming that "SomeList" is a member variable on the OtherForm class that stores this list you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Just define a public property in your form1

```
public List<customerInformation> AllCustomers 
{
  get { return yourList; }
}
```

When opening your `Form2` from `Form1` use this code:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Show(this);
```

Then you can access your customers from Form2:

```
var myCustomerList = ((Form1)Owner).AllCustomers;
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't really understand what means with AllCustomers?